# Result set differences in a SQL Server Compact database PC vs Mobile device

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Interesting problem: I have a SQL Server CE 3.5 database with some data in it. I run a query on the database, using a mobile device and obtain a result set.

This works fine 99% of the time, but on occasion I get records in the database where the query returns an empty result set.

If I take a copy of the same database file from my mobile device and connect to it with Query analyzer, then run the **exact** same query (as copied/pasted from the debugger), the query returns records. The query itself does a JOIN and GROUP BY on two tables by a referential identity key field.

Now if I make a clone the same records involved via a series of:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (EntireFieldListExceptForIDKey)
    SELECT 
        (EntireFieldListExceptForIDKey) 
    FROM 
        MyTable 
    WHERE 
        IDKey = Original
```

The query is now able to correctly assemble a result set on the cloned records on the mobile device.

Can anyone explain this, and possibly how to detect/overcome?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a corrupt index, as both copying the file to your desktop and creating a new table will cause an Index rebuild.

It is recommended to regularly Compact your database to prevent this - also make sure you are using the latest runtime binaries.

Comment: k gotcha, I open with a shrink, which I had assumed was sufficient.

Comment: @DaveMonkman Please mark this a the answer if it solved your issue - TIA